# How to get hour and minute integers from TimeField in Django?

Tags: django, time

I have a `TimeField()` which saves a time. I want to create a model method that finds if user has arrived after 9:00.

```
def late(self):
    t = strptime(self.time, "%H:%M")
    hour = int(t.tm_hour)
    min = t.tm_min
    if hour > 9:
        return True
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `TimeField`, as you said. Let's have a look at [TimeField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield): `A time, represented in Python by a datetime.time instance`, so you shouldn't use strptime on `self.time`. I think that your code should looks like:

```
def late(self):
    return self.time.hour > 9
```

Same for `minute`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `tm_hour` and `tm_min` but `hour` and `minute` respectively.

```
def late(self):
    t = strptime(self.time, "%H:%M")
    return t.hour > 9
```